# How to add a class when the document is started loading and remove class when the document is finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I want to remove class "active" from the body when all components will be loaded.For this purpose, I wrote following jquery code snippets and it's working perfectly in Chrome, but in Firefox the "active" class is not removed by the removeClass function after loading all components.

```
$(document).ready(function($){


      $("body").addClass("active");


});


 $(window).on('load', function () {

      $("body").removeClass("active");

 });
```

Comment: did you check which one runs first?

Comment: @FastSnail load function runs first in Firefox and ready function runs first in Chrome. 
Now I got the cause but how can I achieve it?

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do with this?

Comment: .you may get the expected result if you add more content,images,scripts to the html.

Comment: I want to display a preloader on the screen when the body has class "active"(When the document loads).
like this:
.active .preloader {
    opacity:1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 222;
}

Comment: ready should run first normally and for me that's what i got in both browsers.i think you may get expected result when your page have images scripts.but i don't know why ready doesn't run first in your fx

Comment: There are lots of content, images, scripts in my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything else that could be causing the issue..?

I tried this in Chrome and Firefox and it works fine....doc loads first...Maybe try running this code below to see if this does the same thing on your firefox...?

But it could be FF version or maybe jQuery version too.

I have FF 56.0 (32-bit) it's updating as we speak :-P
and jQuery 2.2.4

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Quick Loading test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>testing</h1>

        <img src="http://www.guoguiyan.com/data/out/113/69175307-large-wallpapers.jpeg">

        <script>


        $(window).on('load', function() {
            $('body').removeClass('active');
            console.log('window load');
        });


        $(document).ready(function($) {
            $('body').addClass('active');
            console.log('doc ready');
        });

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I found this link regarding this...

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3194

So maybe try

```
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('body').removeClass('active');
        console.log('window load');
    });


    $(function() {
        $('body').addClass('active');
        console.log('doc ready');
    });
```

Comment: In my FF Window loads first.

Comment: I added some findings to my original post.  Try without $(document).ready()

Comment: Well this is very odd...maybe for a quick work around you should just write the class active by default into the body, just in case you have a crazy deadline :-S